# How to create a native query to join related tables using @Query annotation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to use the @Query annotation with native query to get information from the database which I intend to use on one of the pages of my web shop application. I tried searching for a similar question but with no luck, so here goes...
Here is the part of the data model in question:

[image]

The Products class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Products {

public enum EProductType {
    FW_FISH, SW_FISH, P_FISH, CRAB_FISH, FW_PLANT, P_PLANT, TANK, FILTER, CO2, FOOD
    }

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
@Column(name = "title")
private String title;
@Column(name = "description")
private String description;
@Column(name = "the_type")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private EProductType productType;
@OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST,
    CascadeType.REFRESH }, mappedBy = "product")
private List<Stock> stock;
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.REFRESH })
@JoinTable(name = "products_order", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"))
private List<Orders> orders;
```

The Stock class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "stock")
public class Stock {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
@Column(name = "price")
private double price;
@Column(name = "quantity")
private int quantity;
@Column(name = "price_date")
private Date priceDate;
@ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH })
@JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
private Products product;
```

The Order class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Orders {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
@Column(name = "date_time")
private LocalDateTime date;
@Column(name = "total_price")
private double totalPrice;
@ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH })
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private Users user;
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "products_order", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "order_id"))
private List<Products> products;
```

And here are the repositories(as requested in the comments):

Stock Repository:

```
public interface IStockRepository extends CrudRepository<Stock, Integer> {}
```

Products Repository:

```
public interface IProductsRepository extends CrudRepository<Products, Integer> {
@Query(value = "SELECT title, the_type, price, quantity FROM Products RIGHT OUTER JOIN Stock ON products.id=stock.product_id", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Products> getProductsInfoForTheHomePage();
}
```

The information i need on the html page are: title from the products table and price and quantity from the stock table.
I am trying with this query in my Repository interface:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT title, the_type, price, quantity FROM Products RIGHT OUTER JOIN Stock ON products.id=stock.product_id", nativeQuery = true)
List<Products> getProductsInfoForTheHomePage();
```

...but when i try to call the method in my controller class a get this exception:
java.sql.SQLException: Column 'id' not found.
This is what the Hibernate logger shows:

```
Hibernate: SELECT title, the_type, price, quantity FROM Products RIGHT OUTER JOIN Stock ON products.id=stock.product_id
```

Since the column is present in the data model I am guessing that the problem is in the query...
Excuse my clumsy english, hope someone can help me out couse I’m stuck on this for a while...

Comment: Can you please add code for the three repositories for Stock, Order and Products. And also please add code for the Order entity.

Comment: Thanks for your time Tatenda! I added the code you requested. You'll notice that it lacks the Orders repository. I don't have such a repository since I didn't think I need it in this phase of the project. In the data model, the 'products' and the 'orders' have a N-N relationship and are connected using a 'products_order' table.

Comment: I don't think I could help further. I've tested your code and its working on my machine. Your native query is also ok as you could see by running it in your DB directly.